# Identify SVG element when another dragged over top

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have several SVG elements in a container. If I drag an element over the top of another element I want to move that element out of the way. I understand that with SVG I would need to redraw all the elements but I need to know the ID of the element I need to move to reposition it.
Tried identifying the element but I end up with the element I am dragging not the one underneath. Is there a way of doing this???
Found lots of answers moving SVG elements around but none where dragging one over another has a direct effect. Maybe I am phrasing the search question wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the question, but you can name any svg element like so:

`<polygon id="somePolygonId"...></polygon>`

More general `<svgelement id="yourId"...></svgelement>`.

I recommend checking snapsvg.io (http://snapsvg.io/), they have a `.drag()` method that could help, along with a `.select("#id")` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jo will look at snapssvg. I can name the elements its how I find out which one has been dragged over that I am struggling with.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you could index every element and its boundaries in objects, and then check if your dragged element boudaries intersect:

    {
        coord: [x, y],
        boundaries: //boundaries,
        isBelow : function(draggedBoundaries){ /*check if below*/ }
    }

And then swipe the array doing `array[i].isBelow(draggedBoundaries)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to move big objects out of the way, and not looking for pixel accuracy, then recursing through the document calling `getBoundingClientRect()` on each element and comparing it to your `x`,`y`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

The top-most one (in an SVG at least) will be the last of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by a combination of finding the drop coordinates and then redrawing the contents of the container.
Thanks for pointing me in right direction